# Using SFINAE and void_t to determine type of elements inside a container

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, void-t

In the code below, I'm trying to determine the type of elements inside a container by checking whether a container C has member `value_type`. If true, I set the type to "value_type". However even when a type doesn't have member value_type and isn't a container, when passed, compiler seems to set the second argument of `HasMemberT_value_type` to True, even though it gives error.

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename = void_t<>>
struct HasMemberT_value_type : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename T>
struct HasMemberT_value_type<T, void_t<typename T::value_type>> : std::true_type
{
};

template<typename T, bool = HasMemberT_value_type<T>::value>
struct ElementTypeT
{
    using Type = typename T::value_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct ElementTypeT<T, false>
{
};

template<typename T>
using ElementType = typename ElementTypeT<T>::Type;

template<typename T>
void printType(T const& c)
{
    std::cout << "Container of " << typeid(ElementType<T>).name() << " elements.\n";
}

int main()
{                                           
    std::array<char, 5> arr;
    char classic[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
                                            //GNU Compiler:
    printType<arr>();                       //Container of c elements.
    printType<classic>();                   //ERROR : "In instantiation of ‘struct ElementTypeT<char [4], true>’: ... error: ‘char [4]’ is not a
                                            //         class, struct, or union type
                                            //         using Type = typename T::value_type;"

}
```

`In instantiation of ‘struct ElementTypeT<char [4], true>`

why is it set to true??

Thank you.

Comment: `ElementType` uses `ElementTypeT<T>::Type` unconditionally, you have to determine what the type should be when being passed a non-container. e.g. For `printType<classic>();`, what should be printed out?

Comment: What is `printType` supposed to do when `classic` is passed to it?

Comment: I'd like it to print "Char". Can I write `using Type = T;` inside the partially specialized ElementTypeT<T,false> so that `char` is chosen? Or it will fail the SFINAE technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printType<arr>()` and `printType<classic>()` won't compile. It should be `printType(arr)` and `printType(classic)`.

The other problem is that `ElementTypeT<T, true>` has a `Type` member, but `ElementTypeT<T, false>` does not. So when you do `using ElementType = typename ElementTypeT<T>::Type` and access that when you do `printType(classic)`, it will fail.

To fix this, modify the specialization so that the array can be deduced:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t I>
struct ElementTypeT<T[I], false>
{
    using Type=T;
};
```

Not sure why `ElementTypeT<char [4], true>` is instaniating in your code. [When I ran it](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6892ef16134c147f) it came up `false` for me.

Here's a simpler way to do this using function overloading and SFINAE:

```
template<class T>
typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type get_value_type( T&& );

template<class R, std::size_t I>
R get_value_type( R(&)[I] );

template<class T>
void printType(T const& c) {
    std::cout << "Container of " << typeid(get_value_type(c)).name() << " elements.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Something must be wrong with my compiler then since I use -std=c++11 and you compiled with c++17 (my linux doesn't have newer gnu gcc versions)..

Comment: BTW to go with your answer (modify my specialization), it seems I'll need to completely go with partial specialization since I'm still getting the same error as above and compiler is not detecting the modified partially specialized one as the better match...